# Cómo recorrer un array para formar una frase con sus elementos?

Tags: javascript

```
function palabrasAFrase(array) {
  // La función llamada  recibe como argumento un arreglo de 'string' y debe devolver un 'string'
  // armando la frase
  // Ej:
  // palabrasAFrase(['Dobby', 'loves', 'socks!]) debe retornar 'Dobby loves socks!'
  // sin espacios ni antes ni después es decir así no => " Dobby loves socks! "
  // Tu código aca:
   
}
```

Comment: me Explicas por favor :(
es que soy nuevo

Comment: Dudo que nadie te ponga un ejercicio sin explicarte primero un mínimo de programación, así que o no has estado prestando atención en clase o tienes pocas ganas de hacer el ejercicio... Todos hemos sido nuevos, si quieres aprender a programar la única manera de hacerlo es esforzándote e intentándolo, si te hacen los ejercicios no aprendes nada.

Comment: Juan Esteban, bienvenido. Voté por cerrar tu pregunta ya que la comunidad tiene ciertas reglas que [puedes conocer aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Te recomiendo que hagas el tour y luego trata de editar tu pregunta con lo que intentaste, aunque hayas fallado en tus intentos, finalmente de eso trata la comunidad. Si la editas, votaré para que la reabran.

Comment: Buenas, considero que el enunciado es bastante claro y de no serlo (Eso según cada uno) no parece haber un esfuerzo por investigar e indagar sobre el tema y simplemente se posteo. No creo que el docente te haya entregado eso sin explicarles nada de programación ya que es un ejercicio extremadamente básico como si hubieses cursado 2 o 3 clases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes recorrer el `array` y concatenar cada uno de sus elementos agregando un espacio al final de cada palabra y eliminando el último caracter con `slice()`.

```js
//Declarar el array
const palabras = ['Dobby', 'loves', 'socks!'];
//Ejecutar la función enviando como parámetro el array
palabrasAFrase(palabras);
//Declarar la función
function palabrasAFrase(palabras) {
  //Inicializar vacía la variable frase
  let frase = '';
  //Recorrer el array palabras
  for (palabra of palabras) {
    //Concatenar cada palabra a la frase agregando un espacio al final
    frase += `${palabra} `;
  }
  //Eliminar el último caracter que sería un espacio en blanco
  frase = frase.slice(0, frase.length - 1);
  //En este punto, puedes hacer lo que se te ocurra...
  //como por ejemplo, mostrar la frase en consola
  console.log(frase);
}
```

Si aún así no lo entiendes, déja un comentario y trato de explicártelo de otra manera.

Comment: Tú mismo has votado para cerrar la pregunta, sin embargo la has respondido... lo veo un poco contradictorio :) Una pregunta como esta no debería ser respondida, no se debe fomentar el uso de SO como sitio para que te hagan los ejercicios, si no que deberíamos evitarlo! No aprenden nada copiando y pegando, que es lo único que hacen con este tipo de preguntas

Comment: @Benito-B hay una tercera opción... He sido docente y hay estudiantes que no entienden la metodología con la que intentas transmitir tu conocimiento. No ataco ni defiendo al PO ya que desconozco su situación pero si hablamos de posibilidades, la que propongo es válida. Ya mismo le explico la razón de mi voto de cierre, no te preocupes por ello.

Comment: @Benito-B ... Por cierto, si te parece contradictoria mi conducta, valida primero la tuya. No considero pertinente atacar a un miembro nuevo sin antes explicarle las normas de la comunidad y desconociendo su situación.

Comment: No vengo a discutir, las reglas son claras. Las preguntas que no demuestran investigación acaban cerradas. El usuario ha venido claramente a que le hagamos los ejercicios tal y como hacen docenas más. No tengo problema con enseñar *a quien quiere aprender*, pero si has sido docente deberías saber de sobra que muchos se meten a informática solo a jugar y pasar el rato y lo único que hacen es copiar y pegar. Yo no he sido docente, pero hasta hace muy poquito era estudiante y he visto de primera mano lo poco que le importa a la mayoría los estudios. Y yo no ataco a nadie... solo he sido directo.